# android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android

> android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
>   androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams

what should I do with this error? I run my app but when I click on the picture, the app stop suddenly ... i just wanted to enlarge the ImageView when i click on it!

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageView imageView;

boolean isImageFitToScreen;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isImageFitToScreen) {
                isImageFitToScreen=false;
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            }else{
                isImageFitToScreen=true;
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            }
        }
    });

}
}


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If you want the best answer, you should post your code.

Comment: Everything is said is the error, you are trying to a .`LinearLayout.LayoutParams` in a `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`. Share your code

Comment: threre is some problem with your code. If you want help, you have to show the relevant part of it.

Answer (score 1):

on lines

`imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` change `LinearLayout` to `ConstraintLayout` as `ImageView`s parent is `ConstraintLayout`